# C# trying to plot datevalue vs timevalue taken from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, charts

I am trying to construct an analysis form which plots date on the x-axis and time on the y-axis. The values are being stored in a SQL Server database connected to the form. The query is running ok with the date value stored in the second column and the time value in the third column.

The error I am getting is

> Specified cast is not valid

This is my code:

```
try
{
    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        datevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(1).ToString().Remove(2);
        timevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(3).ToString();

        itimevalue = DateTime.Parse(timevalue);

        dhours = itimevalue.Hour;
        dminutes = itimevalue.Minute;
        dseconds = itimevalue.Second;

        dtotaltime = dhours + (dminutes / 60) + (dseconds / (60 * 60));

        this.chart1.Series["ExactTarget"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString(3).Remove(2), dtotaltime);

        timevalue = myReader.GetString(4);
        itimevalue = DateTime.Parse(timevalue);
        dhours = itimevalue.Hour;
        dminutes = itimevalue.Minute;
        dseconds = itimevalue.Second;

        dtotaltime = dhours + (dminutes / 60) + (dseconds / (60 * 60));
        this.chart1.Series["ControlPanel"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString(4).Remove(2), dtotaltime); 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: what is your error/problem? no explanation on that?

Comment: Pardon me ... its telling me "Specified cast is not valid"

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What line is throwing the error?  we are not going to run and debug the whole thing for you.

Comment: My issue is that I do not know how to read dates and times from SqlServer can you please assist on that. I think my issue is in datevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(1).ToString().Remove(2);
                    timevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(3).ToString();

Comment: set a breakpoint and find which line is throwing Exception. Check the datataypes in your table and use tryParse instead of parse.
If that does not solves your issue, provide details of the table.

Comment: @MarkPace as you are suggesting that you have issue with datevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(1).ToString().Remove(2); timevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(3).ToString(); check the corresponding datatypes in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Error was in

```
timevalue = myReader.GetDateTime(2).ToString();
```

line needed to be written as

```
timevalue = myReader.GetTimeSpan(2).ToString();
```